# React Native imagebackground with opacity, not text

Tags: react-native

I want to opactiy my imagebackground not text over image
Anyone help me?

```
<ImageBackground                                     
    imageStyle={{ borderRadius: 100 / 4}}
    style={styles.image}
    source={{ uri: "example.com/" + itemData.item.image}}
>
    <View style={styles.includetitle}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>
            {itemData.item.title}
        </Text>
    </View>
</ImageBackground>
```

I tried like this but my text made transparent too...

```
image: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    opacity: 0.5
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass opacity through `imageStyle` props

```
<ImageBackground                                     
    imageStyle={{ borderRadius: 100 / 4}}
    style={styles.image}
    imageStyle={{opacity:0.5}}
    source={{ uri: "example.com/" + itemData.item.image}}
>
    <View style={styles.includetitle}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>
            {itemData.item.title}
        </Text>
    </View>
</ImageBackground>
```

Remove opacity from image obejct of stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Image` instead of `ImageBackground` and wrap with a `View`

```
<View style={style.container}>
  <Image style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill, {resizeMode: 'cover', opacity: 0.5}]}/>
  <View style={styles.includetitle}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>
            {itemData.item.title}
        </Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<ImageBackground
      borderRadius={15}
      fadeDuration={1}
      source={{
        uri: image
          ? image
          : "https://bitsofco.de/content/images/2018/12/Screenshot-2018-12-16-at 21.06.29.png",
      }}
      style={styles.imgcontainer}
    >
      <Text style={styles.name}>{restro.name}</Text>
</ImageBackground>
```

Styles for `imgContainer` and `name`

```
imgcontainer: {
 justifyContent: "flex-end",
 height: 220,
 width: 330,
 padding: 20,
 marginRight: 20,
 marginVertical: 10,
 shadowColor: "#000",
 shadowOffset: {
   height: 5,
 },
 shadowOpacity: 0.5,
 shadowRadius: 10,
 elevation: 10,
 opacity:0.5
},
name: {
 color: "white",
 fontSize: 22,
 fontWeight: "bold",
 letterSpacing: 2,
 textShadowColor: "#000",
 textShadowOffset: {
   width: 2,
   height: 1,
 },
 textShadowRadius: 5,
 opacity:1
},
```